# UISlider track visual issues

Tags: ios, user-interface, slider, uikit, custom-controls

I changed thumb image for `UISlider`. Now I have 2 visual issues:

1. Track does not start at the beginning of the slider
2. Track is not visible for the first 10-20px, than it appears filling the empty space behind

Here are 3 positions of the same slider:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with the size of the pointerImage that probably contains some alpha on sides. Please verify that the pointer image is only 2-3 points wide.

Plus I see some artefact on the tracker image, it is probably not made correctly resizable via resizableImageWithCapInsets: method. that cause its leading end to be deformed.

Here's code that works and does exactly what you want without any glitches:

```
[self.slider setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"slider"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[self.slider setMinimumTrackTintColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
```

Obviously the @"slider" being the name of the point image in Xcode image assets.
And you can put any color there , you don't have to use the built-in dark gray.

Comment: Thumb image has size 4x28, so it doesnt contain any alpha areas.
Also I do not use images for track, just `setMinimumTrackTintColor` and `setMaximumTrackTintColor`

Comment: I used a simple image with the size you specified. The rounding is not there. Try to first achieve standard colouring without rounded borders. That can be dealt with later.